# Matlab fopen error with csv file

Tags: matlab, csv

I'm just trying to import a csv file into Matlab using the textscan function. But everytime i run the program it always throws back this error

> Error using textscan
>   Invalid file identifier. Use fopen to generate a
>   valid file identifier.

But as you can see in the code below i'm using fopen to prepare the file for the use of textscan.

```
S = 'Proto2.csv';
fidi = fopen(S);
C = textscan(fidi, '%f%s%f%f%f%f%f%f%s%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f', 'Delimiter','\n', 'HeaderLines',11, 'CollectOutput',1);
```

Afterwards i'm using C to get access to data i need out of the csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, before proceeding with reading and/or writing operations on a file handle, you must make sure that the handle returned by the `fopen` function is valid. From the [official documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html) of Matlab:

> *fileID = fopen(filename)* opens the file, filename, for binary read
>   access, and returns an integer file identifier equal to or greater
>   than 3. MATLAB® reserves file identifiers 0, 1, and 2 for standard
>   input, standard output (the screen), and standard error, respectively.
>
> **If fopen cannot open the file, then fileID is -1.**

Check your `fidi` variable value before proceeding with `textscan`, I'm pretty sure it is equal to `-1`. This happens either because the file is not found (*if you don't specify a full absolute path, Matlab searches for it within the current working directory*) or because the file has a sharing lock on it (*hence, make sure that it's not being used by other applications while you attempt to read it*).

Comment: Thank you, you were right i just needed to stop giving fopen a full path but rather moved the file in the current directory, it now works like a charm. I still have one problem though, which is that it doesn't seem to import the data right, it just creates a weird 5 row array of which 3 rows are empty one and only one row of my csv file is imported into this array, but in one cell. Is something wrong with my delimiter?

Comment: Unless you show how your file looks like, only you can know.

Comment: `code` 31809,Lisa Herrmann,14:03:50,47.87631872,13.5672457,29,0,0,1.5E+12,172,172,88.1,88.1,0.1,117.1,0.9,0.1,201.3,117.1,114.8,88.2,287.5,287.5 `code`

Comment: this is how a row of the csv file looks i also got it to import correctly but it seems like it doesn't import the numbers but just gives everyone of the 3500 rows NaN values

Comment: I hate `textscan`. It's tricky and tends to split the output based on the underlying variable types. I suggest you to use `readtable` instead... everything will be automagically handled and there is no need to work with file handles. Just type `readtable('myfile.txt')` and everything will work like a charm with no efforts.

Comment: But how can i then access one whole column to store it in a specific variable?

Comment: For example: `row = 10; myvar = mytable(row,:)`. I don't think it's a good idea to cream the whole string representation of a row into a variable. Better to have all data properly parsed into separate columns.

Comment: Am i not getting only the row into the variable now i would need the column not the row. For example in my table i have 3500 rows and 23 columns and i'll need only column 7 stored.

Comment: `myvar = mytable(:,7)` nothing changes, it's just like matrix indexing.